# Aggregate Data in Tables - TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I have 2 tables, `User` and `UserAccess`.

Table - `User`:

```
USER_ID , Client_ID , Start_Date 
1          123        2015-06-30
2          123        2015-06-25
3          123        2015-06-20
5          888        2016-02-10
6          888        2016-02-15
7          888        2016-02-12
```

Table - `UserAccess`:

```
USER_ACCESS_ID  USER_ID  
     10            1          
     11            2          
     12            3
     13            6
     14            7
```

There will be many `Users` records with or without `UserAccess` records. `User_ID` is a PK in `User` table and FK in `UserAccess` table.

I have to write a generic query to return one user record per client instead there are more than one User records for the same client.

Pick `User` with the earliest `Start_Date`, and if there is a record with a corresponding `UserAccess`, it will be consider a winner over one without an `UserAccess` record..

The query should return only 2 records from the `User` table as

- User # 3 as it has the earliest `Start_Date` with `UserAccess` record
- User # 5 has the earliest `StartDate` but no `UserAccess` record so User # 7 should be picked as this has the User Access record with earliest date.

Hope I was able to explain.

Thanks in advance.

Regards

Ally

Comment: i have tried CTE with checking counts on the child table , but not able to get the write results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will that query work for you?

```
;WITH Users as (
    SELECT u.*, a.USER_ACCESS_ID 
    , RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Client_ID 
            ORDER BY CASE WHEN a.USER_ID is Null 
                    Then 1 ELSE 0 END, u.Start_Date) as ToPick
    FROM tbl_User as u
    LEFT JOIN tbl_UserAccess as a 
    ON u.USER_ID = a.USER_ID
)
SELECT USER_ID , Client_ID , Start_Date, USER_ACCESS_ID
FROM Users
WHERE ToPick = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks you did it right , i did it a different way but your way was better

Comment: thank you this worked also . We did it a different way but your way is better